# Exim4 root email forwarding failure

Tags: email-server, ubuntu-14.04, exim

Before anyone asks, yes, I've read the other 50 threads about this, but none have worked. (And my reputation is low enough that I can't seem to comment on existing threads, hence having to restart this post again.)

I've sucessfully set up mdadm forwarding to servermonitoring@example.org (hosted by Google) using exim4, but any emails sent to root refuse to route correctly. All end up being sent straight out to root@example.org, which blows up, as it does not currently exist. I've run newalises, restarted exim4, etc, and no joy. I know this has to be simple, but I am just not quite understanding what the problem is.

Couple quick notes before the config files appear:

1. rDNS is not set up, as this is a random server at home. (MX record for the domain points to gmail, as gmail is handling the actual domain email hosting.)
2. [This thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235112/exim-email-to-root-ignores-etc-aliases-and-root-forward-always-used-qualif) seems to be close to correct, but my server's hostname is not of the format asdf.example.org, so I'm not quite sure how to translate it. (Various attempts haven't quite worked.)

System hostname:

```
root@zetaServer:~# hostname
zetaServer
```

Contents of /etc/aliases:

```
postmaster:    root
root: servermonitoring@example.org, /root/mailbox
```

Contents of /root/.forward:

```
servermonitoring@example.org
```

Contents of /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_other_hostnames=''
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='smtp.gmail.com::587'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='false'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

Contents of /var/log/exim4/mainlog after sending a test email:

```
root@zetaServer:~# echo test | mail -s "test message" root
root@zetaServer:~# tail /var/log/exim4/mainlog -n 3
2016-11-24 20:55:29 1cA7bl-0006Xf-K0 <= root@example.org U=root P=local S=482
2016-11-24 20:55:30 1cA7bl-0006Xf-K0 => root@example.org R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost H=gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com [74.125.28.109] X=TLS1.2:RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1:128 DN="C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc,CN=smtp.gmail.com" A=gmail_login C="250 2.0.0 OK 1480046130 c15sm63433639pfd.36 - gsmtp"
2016-11-24 20:55:30 1cA7bl-0006Xf-K0 Completed
```

Gmail Error:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

root@example.org
```

I know I have to be close... Just need a little help.

Comment: Are you sure that exim use `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHA! I figured it out!

I needed to set the hostname of my server itself (zetaServer) as the system mail name rather than example.org! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are on a home network, it is unlikely that you will get valid rDNS, and your hostname likely won't be valid.  Although, you should have something like `myhost.example.org`.

Try configuring a password entry for gmail in `/etc/exim/passwd.client`.  Check the auth configuration to verify that the client authentication code is not commented out.  (I believe it is enabled by default.)  Use valid credentials for your gmail account.

Check your log file(s) in `/var/log/exim4` for any messages that indicate why the message failed.   The failed messages should have been bounced to a local account.  The log file should show a local delivery of the bounce message.

Exim will not deliver as root, so if you want local delivery for root use `real-root` as the local address.  It is best to alias root to a local user and have that user aliased for remote delivery.  Bounces and local deliveries can then be done more easily.   For local delivery when using the smarthost setup, prefix the desired user with `real-` which will bypass the remote alias.

Comment: So I have a valid email address and password. Emails to servermonitoring@example.org work just fine. Seems to be an issue with exim4 not redirecting emails destined for root to that address for some reason. 

Also, you can see above that there was no error in the exim4 log. The issue is that exim4 isn't rewriting the root emails to the valid account before firing them out.

Comment: @ZetaSyanthis Most system processes mail eventually get redirected to `root`.  You should have an entry in `/etc/aliases` to redirect root something like `root : servermonitoring@example.org`.